# Link rdl report to multiple parent reports in CRM 2011

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created some reports to go into CRM, one of these reports uses the other as a sub-report and I have linked the two together so that it all works. But now I have a second report that will need the same sub-report on it. So is there any way that I can link a sub-report to multiple parents so that both can see it? Or will I need to have a copy of the sub-report for each report I want to use it in?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience you can only link a sub report to one parent via the Dynamics interface.

I am looking at other options to get around this at the moment, but haven't found any as of yet.

I am currently creating two sub-reports in cases like this.

Comment: That's the same conclusion i've come to, there doesn't seem to be a way to do it. So I've created copies of the sub-report and uploaded them separately instead.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, and for future reference:

I solved this issue by using a IF/ELSE structure, this way I can use the parent to select which selection to make. When the sub-report is run directly it uses the CRM Automatic Filtering context. When the sub-report is provisioned with an account ID from a parent it uses this to determine the context.

```
IF(@AccountId IS NULL OR @AccountId = '')
BEGIN
SELECT TOP(3) ava_campaignparticipationid AS CampaignParticipationId
FROM Filteredava_campaignparticipation AS CRMAF_Filteredava_campaignparticipation
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT ava_campaignparticipationid AS CampaignParticipationId
FROM Filteredava_CampaignParticipation
WHERE ava_accountid = @AccountId
AND ava_participation = 915240002
END
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Old though this question may be, I just wanted to back up [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73228/andrew)'s answer. Looking at the Report entity in the Solution, you can see that Report:Parent Report is defined as a N:1 relationship; one report can have multiple sub-reports, but a given sub-report can only have one parent.
[image: Screenshot from within Microsoft Dynamics 365 showing the N:1 relationships for the Report entity. One row of the list is highlighted: {'Schema Name':'report_parent_report', 'Primary Entity':'Report', 'Related Entity':'Report', 'Type of Behavior':'Parental', 'Field Name':'Parent Report', 'State':'Managed', 'Customizable':'True', 'Field Description':'Unique identifier of the parent report.'}]